# Is there a drawback to specifying a large size for SqlCommand parameters?

Tags: c#, parameters, sqlcommand

I'm writing an application that executes queries coming from special text files with parameters coming from a user.

I use code similar to the following to add parameters:

```
IDbCommand command = GetSomeCommand();
object parameter = GetSomeParameter();
IDbDataParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "Param1";
if (parameter is string s)
{
  parameter.Size = (s.Length + 9) / 10 * 10;
  parameter.Value = s;
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

The rounding up to the next 10 is done to flood the query plan cache a little less. 
My question is: Could I just always use -1 (for VARCHAR(MAX)) or 8000 for the size or does this have any significant drawbacks?

Comment: No, there are no significant drawbacks.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing in the query. Incorrect sizes may cause excessive memory grants and poor query plans in general as things are converted to and fro. On the other hand, if you're just doing single-statement inserts or something along those lines, the declared size of varying parameters will not effectively matter.

Comment: Consider using the `optimize for ad-hoc workloads` option on the server. This is rarely a bad idea anyway, but it's especially good if you're expecting, well, an ad-hoc workload. "Rounding" parameter sizes may actually be a little counterproductive with this option in effect, because these ad-hoc queries are unlikely to benefit much from reused query plans. From a pure plan reuse point of view, the "let's make everything `NVARCHAR(MAX)`" approach is great. But, as I said, beware potential memory and conversion issues. Measuring a real workload is always the best idea.

Comment: The queries aren't really ad-hoc. There's a limited number of queries and a defined set of parameters per query. From the comments so far, I think I can use MAX.